# 64 bit Ubuntu on 32 bit windows xp by daemon tools

Tags: dual-boot, 64-bit, 32-bit, windows-xp, burning

I am currently using a 32 bit processor with xp and wanna dual boot it with Ubuntu. Should I download 32 bit Ubuntu or 64 bit Ubuntu? I also wanted to ask if I can use daemon tools instead of burning a cd drive? If no then is there another way to install Ubuntu without burning the iso file?

Answer (score 1):

You must install 32 bit ubuntu when you only have a 32 bit processor.
Instead of using a DVD put the content of the iso file to an USB stick.
You can use 'diskpart' to prepare the USB stick and make it bootable.

Comment: how about using Daemon tools or somet similar softwares? Is it risky or safe?

Comment: @abhishah901 - sorry, this is not a Windows support forum ! But I can tell you that most 3rd party tools sometimes work, sometimes don't. When you want to or have to do it from Windows I recommend to use diskpart. This built-in Windows command line tool always did the job. Concerning Daemon Tools : simply try out whether it works or not ...